# What is the conditional for location.hash on the page root?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following:

```
    console.log(location.hash)
    if(location.hash = ''){
        console.log('home')
    }
```

What conditional should I set to get the console to log home on for example
example.com/

Comment: 1 equals sign is assignment not comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will log home on example.com/

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/'){
    console.log('home')
}
```

You need to use the **pathname** property, not **hash**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to test if a hash exists?

```
// If there is no hash
if(!window.location.hash){
    console.log("no hash");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `location.hash` will not be set:

```
if (location.hash == null)
if (!location.hash)
```

And in your code, you are assigning! Not comparing! Use `==`!

Comment: I don't think `location.hash` ever returns `null` or `false`.